# Limit of probability distribution of $X_{i+1},Y_{i+1} \overset{d}= f(X_i,Y_i)$ for $i \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

#### The Question

Imagine a setup where you start with two iid random variables $X_0,Y_0\sim\mathcal D_0$, where $\mathcal D_0$ is some discrete distribution over $[N]$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$. You also have a function $f:N\times N\longrightarrow N$, and you define $\mathcal D_{i+1}$ to be the distribution of $f(X_i, Y_i)$, and take $X_{i+1},Y_{i+1} \sim \mathcal D_{i+1}$. For which $f$ does the limit $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty} \mathcal D_i$ exist? How to calculate it?

For the sake of simplicity you can assume that $\mathcal D_0$ is the uniform distribution over $[N]$.

### An Attempt

I thought of "pivoting" the problem, in the sense of defining $p_i(n) := \mathrm{Prob}( X_i = n)$, which means
$$
\begin{split}
    p_{i+1}(n) = \mathrm{Prob}(f(X_i,X'_i)=n) &= \!\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{(m,k) \in f^{-1}(n)}\!\!\!\!\!\! p_i(m)p_i(k) \\
 &= \sum_{m\in[N]}\sum_{k\in[N]} p_i(m) p_i(k)
                 \begin{cases}
                      1 & n=f(m,k) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}
                 \end{cases}
\end{split}
$$
Maybe this set of coupled recurrence relations can somehow be translated into a set of ODEs, and then one could apply Picard-Lindelöf?

I'd be happy for any pointers!!!

*PS: I heavily edited the question after realising that there was no good way of formulating it with balls and colors. Thanks for pointing that out!*

Comment: Since you have infinitely many balls, the ratio does not change.

Comment: I rephrased it. What I mean is the density, fraction, or the likelihood of a ball being a certain color. I hope that makes it more clear!

Comment: Still, modifying an infinite set by a finite amount does nothing.

Comment: Well if you do it at an infinite rate... but not so important. I replaced it with a very large pool. In the end I'm just looking at the stationary distribution, kind of like a Markov chain's (but this here is a nonlinear dependence).

Comment: If you have a large finite pool and repeatedly remove two and add one, the infinite-time limit is that there are no balls in the pool.

Comment: Thanks both for pointing this out. Lesson learnt: never try to oversimplify what you actually want to ask.

Comment: I thought the original formulation (after changing "an infinite pool" to "a very large pool") can be saved simply by replacing the two drawn balls with _two_ balls of the new color. :)

Comment: maybe. The current formulation is more precise though. But I'm sceptical about a generic answer being possible here: quadratic maps tend to behave chaotically.

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer / too long for a comment.**

Your equations are necessary for any limits that exist, but they are not sufficient to show limits exist.  This is the difference between a stationary solution vs actually tending to such a solution from a given starting point.

Here is a simple $f$ which **does not even depend on its second argument**, where the limit does not exist.  Consider $N \ge 3$.  For any $y$:

- $f(1, y) = N$
- $f(k, y) = 1$ where $k \neq 1$.

Starting with the uniform distribution, all future distributions will have only $p(1)$ and $p(N)$ be non-zero, but their values will oscillate between $\frac1N$ and $\frac{N-1}{N}$.  The stationary solution is of course both values equal $\frac12$ but this will not be reached from the uniform starting distribution.

Obviously my answer is inspired by Markov Chains, where stationary and limit are related but not the same thing.  So if you are looking for limiting behavior, there are other things to consider besides the "quadratic map" issue.

Comment: Curious.
I found a paper:
https://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/RSW92/corrected.pdf
that suggests (Sec. 1.3, first sentence) that if f is symmetric, then the system always converges to a fixed point. It appears this is compatible with your counterexample.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with that area in general.  In particular, note that my example only applies to your current (as of 2021-04-26) wording of the question, where $D_{i+1} \sim f(X_i, Y_i)$.  If you think back to your earlier (and flawed) wording with balls in a large pool, clearly this example doesn't oscillate.  In a sense, when you "fixed" the flaw in your "balls in large pool" wording, you ended up with quite a different question.

Comment: Yes; the balls and pool question was my attempt at reducing the problem to something simpler, but it turned out to be not what I wanted to ask.
Thanks anyway!!!